# `for-each` over list of functions given `#<void>` in Racket

Tags: foreach, scheme, racket

I am playing around with some declarative graphics stuff in Racket v6.5. For that I have defined a macro that executes a list of functions. This is then used in the drawing callback.

```racker
#lang racket/gui

(define-syntax-rule (execute-functions flist arg)
  (for-each
   (lambda (function)
     [(function arg)])
   flist))

(define-syntax-rule
  (text str (at x y))
  (lambda (dc)
    (send dc set-scale 1 1)
    (send dc set-text-foreground "blue")
    (send dc draw-text str x y)))

(define-syntax-rule
  (drawing items ...)
  (lambda (dc) (execute-functions (list items ...) dc)))

(define my-drawing
  (drawing (text "hi" (at 1 1)) (text "lo" (at 20 20))))

(define frame (new frame%
                   [label "Example"]
                   [width 300]
                   [height 300]))
(new canvas% [parent frame]
             [paint-callback (lambda (canvas dc) (my-drawing dc))])
(send frame show #t)
```

The above progam will result in errors:

```
. . application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<void>
```

Which are traced to the function execution in drracket: `(function arg)`.

If I check for void it works ok:

```
(define-syntax-rule (execute-functions flist arg)
  (for-each
   (lambda (function)
     [if (void? function) void (function arg)])
   flist))
```

But I am a bit concerned that it is being passed void in the first place as I don't know why that is. Is it something that is expected from a list of functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra set of parentheses (well, in this case square brackets, but they are equivalent) in the definition of your `execute-functions` macro.

```
(define-syntax-rule (execute-functions flist arg)
  (for-each
   (lambda (function)
     [(function arg)])
;    ^--------------^------- these brackets shouldn’t be here
   flist))
```

The call itself, `(function arg)`, may return `#<void>`, and the result is attempted to be invoked as a function itself (provided no arguments) since it is surrounded with parentheses/brackets, which denote function calls in Lisp/Scheme/Racket when used as expressions.

---

As a separate issue, though, your use of `define-syntax-rule` everywhere instead of simply using `define` is confusing to me and doesn’t seem to make much sense. These things do not need to be macros—always prefer functions over macros when you don’t need the syntax-transformation functionality of macros.

Functions are more flexible and can be used higher-order (that is, they can be passed as values), but macros cannot. Also, wanton use of macros will generate massive amounts of code, effectively forcing the compiler to inline every single “function call”. Use them when you need them, but you don’t need them here.

The `execute-functions` and `drawing` functions can be replaced with ordinary functions with barely any modification:

```
(define (execute-functions flist arg)
  (for-each
   (lambda (function)
     (function arg))
   flist))

(define (drawing . items)
  (lambda (dc) (execute-functions items dc)))
```

The custom syntax for the `text` macro does not seem worth it to me at all, but if you *really* want it, then you might want to pull the functionality into a separate, ordinary function that the macro defers to instead:

```
(define ((text-proc str x y) dc)
  (send dc set-scale 1 1)
  (send dc set-text-foreground "blue")
  (send dc draw-text str x y))

(define-syntax-rule (text str (at x y))
  (text-proc str x y))
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, the change mentioned works great. 

The reason there are so many macros is that I was doing this as an exercise to start understanding them before moving on to extending the language. I want to make a declarative graphics language of sorts. I reduced what I was doing down to illustrate the problem but stopped short at re-defining the define-syntax bits.

Comment: What you say about code-size and convention regarding macros is interesting though. My initial intuition upon discovering them was that they should be used for anything that doesn't require access to run-time variables as run-time performance will be improved.

Comment: @kasbah No, that’s definitely *not* true. Functions do that just fine—you only need macros when you want to define your own syntax for something or if you want to run arbitrary code at compile-time (the latter of which `syntax-rules` macros can’t do, anyway). As for performance: the compiler will take care of that for you 99% of the time, and it will do a better job than you! It will automatically inline small functions, and it will avoid bloating the code size with tons of inlining. Turning everything into macros will likely *decrease* performance, not improve it.